# Using a single loginProcessingUrl for multiple identity providers in spring security saml2Login

Tags: spring-security, saml

I'm trying to let users setup SAML identity providers dynamically in our application using spring-security 5.7.x. When configuring saml2 using the HttpSecurity instance, one can provide a `loginProcessingUrl` which by default must contain a `registrationId` path variable, e.g. `/saml2/sso/{registrationId}`.

The `Saml2AuthenticationTokenConverter` will then use the `registrationId` parameter from the request and retrieve the `RelyingPartyRegistration` through the `RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository`.

I would like to have a static loginProcessingUrl, without having the `registrationId` of the identity provider in the URL.

My question is: When i trigger the SAML authentication request, can i somehow add the `registrationId` to the SAML request, so that is returned by the SamlResponse from the IDP, so that i can resolve the RelyingPartyRegistration based on the content of the SamlResponse, not the request URI that contains the response?

I know that this in principle works (not tied to spring-security), because that's how the AWS cognito SAML integration works - there you can register multiple identity providers, which all have the same redirectUrl, but you have to provide a unique `providerName` string for each configured IDP - so i assume that cognito somehow passes that identifier to the IDP and it will return it in the response.

Answer (score 1):

With spring 6.2 you can remove {registrationId} part and make it common for all IDPs. Please follow the URL below:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/saml2/login/authentication.html#saml2-response-processing-endpoint

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).